# Making meteor rerender "unchanged" fields

Tags: javascript, meteor, meteor-blaze

The (simplified) template below renders a form with two input fields, pre-filled based on the data context. The form can be opened for several different data contexts (though only one at a time), in which case I want all fields to be rerendered with the new data - which *mostly* happens.

```
<template name="form">
    <input type="text" value="{{title}}">
    <input type="text" value="{{start_value}}">
</template>
```

The problem arises when two data contexts have the same value for either field - e.g. it is very common for `start_value` to be 0. In this case, the corresponding input field will not be rerendered when the data context switches. Perhaps an example is in order:

1. User opens form for a data context with `start_value = 0`
2. User changes the input field corresponding to `start_value` from `0` to `12`
3. User closes the form without saving
4. User opens form for another data context with `start_value = 0`
5. The field corresponding to `start_value` still says `12`

This seems to happen for all (primitive) identical values. Using a helper to return the value changes nothing but does confirm that the helper is rerunning as expected.

I can work around this with an autorun-afterflush on the template instance to explicitly update the input fields, but is there a more idiomatic way to make Meteor rerender "unchanged" fields?

### Edit:

Here is [working example](https://gist.github.com/raihle/) (and by working I mean it shows what doesn't work).

Just create those two files in the client directory of a clean Meteor project and you should be able to observe the behavior. Items 1 and 2 have the save `value` and so the second input field will not change when you switch between them even if you have altered it manually. Items 3 and 4 have the same `title` and exhibit similar behavior.

Comment: Can you post your template helpers and other js code? I haven't encountered this behavior myself.

Comment: @FullStack I've added a complete example to the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not exactly sure if I'm answering your question but if your trying to clear a value after the user closes the form so it does not repopulate with that value on reopen, then you could use [the onDestroyed function](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/template_onDestroyed)

to do any clean up you need, such as clearing a session which appears to be what you set when the form is opened.

Comment: `These callbacks are called when an occurrence of a template is taken off the page for any reason and not replaced with a re-rendering`. Unfortunately, the form is (in most cases) immediately re-rendered which means that `onDestroyed` is not called.

Comment: Ah, sorry I was slightly confused as to the behavior when you said "user closes the form". How is the form closed? could you potentially just capture the event that closes it and reset session there?

Comment: Ah. I didn't include it in the example, but the form is placed inside a bootstrap modal which can be dismissed. I could catch that, clear the selected item, and prevent the form from rendering until a new selection is made, maybe?

Comment: Yea that is the approach I would go for. If the modal has something similar to an onClose function that can be called, you could reset the values there. Reading your response about session being updated but not the input, you could also try to use jquery to ensure the value is "" (or whatever you want) when rendered. `$('.input-class').val('');`

Comment: Yeah, clearing the fields "manually" was my current workaround, but I want to stay away from that for various reasons. I guess destroying and rendering the template from scratch is acceptable in my use so I'll do that for now. +1 since this solves my problem, but I'll leave the question open in the hopes of a more general solution.